# Python Dictionary duplicates

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have 2 lists

```
list_a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
list_b = ['good', 'bad', 'worst', 'cheap', 'waste', 'waste1']
```

I am trying to write a python script and my mapping element in `list_a` with element in `list_b` and  if someone inputs value `1` all the related values should populate. Eg if I enter `1` as input parameter the output should be

```
good
bad
```

if I enter `2` as input parameter output should be

```
worst
cheap
```

I tried python dictionaries but dictionary is not allowing duplicate keys. Is there is a way to achieve this in Python?

Comment: Hint: your dictionary values can be lists.

Comment: Dictionaries can contain lists like `{1: ['good', 'bad'], 4: ['waste']}`

Comment: I got this idea. Is there is a way to do this?

Comment: He literally just typed it for you.

Answer (score 3):

A rare use case for [`itertools.compress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress):

```
idx = get_index(...)  # Get index to check by whatever means

for x in itertools.compress(list_b, (idx == i for i in list_a)):
    print(x)
```

`compress` takes an iterable of values, and an iterable of "truthy or falsy" values, returning the items from the first iterable when the second iterable provides a truthy paired value. So in this case, we want items from `list_b`, when the value in `list_a` matches the provided index, which we compute on the fly with a generator expression.

Mind you, for repeated lookups, a `dict` is a better bet. Simply using:

```
lookup = {1: ['good', 'bad'], 2: ['worst', 'cheap'], 4: ['waste'], 5: ['waste1']}
```

will allow you to efficiently do `for x in lookup[idx]: print(x)` as many times as needed (possibly catching `KeyError` to ignore the case when the key doesn't exist, or to produce a friendlier error message).

Comment: Why is it rare?

Comment: @swimingduck: Because it's really only useful for doing a single streaming pass of huge data (inputs too large to hold in memory at once); for multiple passes and/or small data, you could just make a lookup `dict` of the form I added in my edit.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks for the solution. Could you please let me know how can we generate lookup = {1: ['good', 'bad'], 2: ['worst', 'cheap'], 4: ['waste'], 5: ['waste1']} from above lists

Comment: @sudhir: `result = collections.defaultdict(list)`, `for k, v in zip(list_a, list_b): result[k].append(v)`, `result = dict(result)` (last bit optional, to convert back to plain `dict` that won't auto-vivify missing keys).

Comment: Awesome. This is what I am looking. I am so dumb I have been using tuple(zip(list_a, list_b)) instead of dict

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the dictionary out of the two lists. Might save some of your typing...

```
list_a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5]
list_b = ['good', 'bad', 'worst', 'cheap', 'waste', 'waste1']

d = {}
for x, y in zip(list_a, list_b):
  if d.get(x):
    d[x] += [y]
  else:
    d[x] = [y]

print(d[2])
```